# Добавить элемент на страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function openD(id, last) {
    currentId = id;
    lastMessage = last;
    nameInterlocutor = $("#n" + id).html();
    photoInterlocutor = $("#av" + id).attr("src");
    $.post("/openD", {id: id}, dialog);
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        if(!bysy) {
            getMessage();
        }
    }, 3000);
}

function getMessage() {
    $.post("/getMessage", {userId: currentId, messageId: lastMessage}, displayMessage);
}

function displayMessage(data) {
    bysy = true;
    var a = JSON.parse(data);
    if(data.length > 0) {
        var chat = $("#chat");
        $.each(a, function() {
            alert(this.text);
            $("#chat").append('<div class="message me">' +
            '<img src="' + photoInterlocutor + '" />' +
            '<div><p><strong>' + nameInterlocutor + ' : </strong>' + this.text + '<br/>' + messageDate.toLocaleDateString("ru", {
                hour : "numeric",
                minute : "numeric"
            }) + '</p></div>' +
            '</div>');
            lastMessage = this.id;
        });
    };
    bysy = false;
}
```

Сообщение он получает, alert выполняет (вставил для отладки), но вот новые сообщения на страницу не выводит

Comment: `$("#chat").append(/* что-то страшное */)` на вашем месте я бы не стал писать такие страсти прямо в функции append, если строки получаются такими сложными, то стоит задуматься о шаблонизаторе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже что после `alert` происходит ошибка, посмотрите в отладчике (обычно он открывается в браузере по F12).

Возможно, переменные `photoInterlocutor` и `nameInterlocutor` не определены, я не вижу в коде их объявления.
Либо ошибка происходит в методе `messageDate.toLocaleDateString`

PS: Старайтесь не использовать глобальные переменные, это очень плохая практика, потому как это значительно усложняет процесс отладки.